# Find the max value in a column in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This seems really simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Most of my background is in Python and R and this would be exceedingly simple, but I can't figure out how to do it in D3.

How do I find the max value in a column?

For example, say I have a csv:

```
country,gdp
USA,55
Japan,22
Kuwait,10
```

I load it in to D3 with

```
    function getData() {
        d3.csv("gdp.csv", function(d) {
            gdpData = d;
        });   
    }
```

now how do I do this? I just want to return the value `55` (the highest value in the `gdp` column).

In Python, this would just be `np.max(gdpData['gdp'])` or in R `max(gdpData$gdp)`.

I have tried `Math.max(gdpData.gdp)` and `Math.max(gdpData['gdp'])` and a variety of other things using `.keys()` but to no avail. I think I am just fundementally misunderstanding how D3 is representing the table of data.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loading your data, you can do the following to get the max:

```
var max = d3.max(gdpData, function(d) { return d.gdp; } );
```

[This link](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#statistics) will probably be helpful for you to understand the different operations you can do on arrays via `d3`.

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't get this to work. However, I did get the `data.map...` below to work, except that it was failing because the array was actually strings, not numbers, so I had to changed it to:
`var max = d3.max(data.map(d => d.gdp).map(Number));`
However, Gerardo says this should be the accepted answer, so I'm accepting it for future users. Thanks to both of you for the help.

Comment: @seth127 as the OP, you can accept any answer you want, it's your right. I just said that my answer was an explanation of this answer and, that being the case, shouldn't be the accepted one. However, if this answer is not working, ask the answerer what can be the problem, and don't accept non-working answers: that can be actually bad for future readers. Also, regarding the string/number issue, I just added that information in my answer, have a look again.

Comment: Also, others may need to add a + symbol if their numbers are strings (in quotes in the data source):
return +d.gdp;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450837/d3-js-how-can-i-get-the-maximum-value-of-a-specified-key-in-an-object

Answer (score 1):

(this is just an addendum to [sparta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588041/5768908))

You have two initial problems here:

1. I don't know the rest of your code, but it seems to me that you're trying to assign the data array to a global called `gdpData`. That won't work because `d3.csv` is asynchronous. Besides that, `d3.csv` won't return anything, so you cannot assign it to the variable either.
2. You're using `d` as the first parameter in the callback function. Don't do that, it introduces an unnecessary confusion, since `d` is normaly used in idiomatic D3 as the datum parameter in most of anonymous functions. Use `data`, `dataset`, `myData` or anything like.

That all being said, change your function to this:

```
d3.csv("gdp.csv", function(data) {
    //code here
});
```

So, after this first step, let's see what `d3.csv` does:

Given your CSV, `d3.csv` creates an array of objects, where the property name is the CSV header and the property value is the following rows. In your case, this is the data array (check the console):

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());
console.log(data);
```

```css
pre{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">country,gdp
USA,55
Japan,22
Kuwait,10</pre>
```

(note: I'm using a pre element to load the data because I can't upload a CSV in the Stack snippet)

Then, to get the maximum value, just use the code in sparta's answer, with `d3.max`, which:

> Returns the maximum value in the given array using natural order. If the array is empty, returns undefined. An optional accessor function may be specified, which is equivalent to calling array.map(accessor) before computing the maximum value.

So, since you have an array of objects, you'll need:

```
var max = d3.max(data, d => d.gdp);
```

Which is the same of:

```
var max = d3.max(data.map(d => d.gdp));
```

The `data.map` returns this array:

```
["55", "22", "10"]
```

And `d3.max` finds the highest value in that returned array. Pay attention to the fact that `d3.csv` parses the CSV values as **strings** (as you can see in the above array), not numbers, even if the values are originally numbers.

Check the demo:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());
var max = d3.max(data, d => d.gdp);
console.log(max);
```

```css
pre{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">country,gdp
USA,55
Japan,22
Kuwait,10</pre>
```